# K6 Load Testing - How to calculate accurate response times when using the rps option

Tags: k6

I am recording how long each request takes by capturing Date.now() before and after the request.

I am doing this because the inbuild metric for the response time only records the time taken for the FIRST REQUEST and not for any redirects that it follows.

My method was working fine until I started using the rps option.

The rps option throttles how many requests per second are sent.

The problem that this is causing is that my manual calculations are going up even though the HTTP_REQ_DURATION is roughly the same.

I presume this is because of the RPS throttle i.e. it is WAITING and this is causing my calc using Date.now() to go up - which is not an accurate reflection of what is happening.

How can I calculate the total time taken for a response to a request including all redirects when I am using the rps option?

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against using the RPS option and using an [arrival-rate executor](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/arrival-rate) instead, for example, [`constant-arrival-rate`](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/executors/constant-arrival-rate).

Alternatively, you can set the [`maxRedirects` option](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/options#max-redirects) to `0`, so k6 doesn't handle redirects itself. Then, when you handle the redirects yourself, you can get the [`Response` object](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-http/response) for each of the requests, not just the last one. Then you can sum their `Response.timings.duration` (or whatever you care about) and add the result in your custom metric, it will not contain any artificial delays caused by `--rps`.

Comment: Thanks na--. If I use arrival-rate-executor will my timings be correct or still include artifical delays?

Comment: With the rps option, k6 will artificially restrict the amount of requests/s if they exceed the threshold you specified. With the arrival-rate executors, you can instead specify exactly how many iterations/s (and thus, requests/s) you want, so there's no restriction or artificial delays.